# Hangfire managing dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, hangfire

I have a generic repository class that has two constructors:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseMongoEntity
{
    public Repository(ILogDbSettings dbSettings, string? collectionName = null)
    {   
    }

    public Repository(IDbSettings dbSettings)
    {
    }
}
```

I am registering my repositories that will use main database like:

```
_ = serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IRepository<Customer>>(provider =>
        {
            var dbSettings = provider.GetService<IDbSettings>();
            return new Repository<Customer>(dbSettings!);
        });
```

and I am registering types that will use log database like:

```
 _ = serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IRepository<CustomerLog>>(provider =>
        {
            var dbSettings = provider.GetService<ILogDbSettings>();    
            return new Repository<CustomerLog>(dbSettings);
        });
```

my hangfire registration code is like:

```
services.AddHangfire(config =>
            {
                var storageOptions = new MongoStorageOptions
                {
                    MigrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
                    {
                        BackupStrategy = new NoneMongoBackupStrategy(),
                        MigrationStrategy = new DropMongoMigrationStrategy()
                    },
                    CheckQueuedJobsStrategy = new CheckQueuedJobsStrategy()
                };

                var settings = configuration.GetRequiredSection("HangfireDbSettings").Get<HangfireDbSettings>()!;

                _ = config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
                    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                    .UseMongoStorage(settings.ConnectionString, settings.DatabaseName, storageOptions);
            })
            .AddHangfireServer();
```

This works well in my application but I am using hangfire to log everything to log db. Somehow, hangfire recreates the repository instances from the constructor that takes `IDbSettings` which causes issues in my app.

My Enqueue code is like:

```
public class CustomerLogService : ICustomerLogService
{
    private readonly IBackgroundJobClient _backgroundJobClient;
    private readonly IRepository<CustomerLog> _customerLogRepository;
    public RestaurantAppEmailQueueItemService(IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient, IRepository<CustomerLog> customerLogRepository)
    {
        _backgroundJobClient = backgroundJobClient;
        _customerLogRepository = customerLogRepository;
    }
    public void Insert(CustomerLog log)
    {
        _ = _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => _customerLogRepository.InsertAsync(log));
    }
}
```

When I implemented a custom job activator I realized that when a scheduled job tries to create a new instance it tries the get an instance of `Repository<CustomerLog>`  not `IRepository<CustomerLog>`
and when I give a different service collection to hangfire with my custom JobActivator it complains about it can't found an instance of `Repository<CustomerLog>`

Is there any custom configuration that I should do or any idea?

Thanks

======SOLUTION=====
I found the solution by using an overload of Enqueue function like:

```
_ = _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IRepository<MyClass>>(p => p.InsertAsync(item));
```

Somehow hangfire tries to reconstruct the instance which is solved bu DI already and can not find the correct instance. By this function I also realized that singleton instances are used bu hangfire and not constructed once more

Comment: Please share the code where you register the Hangfire job that uses `IRepository<CustomerLog>`.

Comment: By calling `AddHangfire()` on service collection you are telling Hangfire to use default .NET built-in DI container to resolve services. [This](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.NetCore/HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L98) is how it is registered within service collection and [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.NetCore/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.cs#L34) is the job activator implementation that uses mentioned DI.

Comment: So, maybe you should ask yourself a question, why DI is resolving your service in that way? Did you try to resolve it yourself to see if it's resolved using correct dependencies?

Comment: Yes definetely I tested and debugged the way how log repository is created but I cant debug how hangfire creates it. when I put console log to constructors in my app correct repository is called but in hangfire it is not. I added how I register hangfire